# CoreNLP MaxentTagger architecture options - meaning and effectiveness

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I'm trying to train a custom parts-of-speech tagger from the CoreNLP library (using the edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger class, to be specific), and am struggling with what the options mean (am not a linguist) and what's the most effect combination(s). I've tried with some default options that came with the out of box download of CoreNLP library, and also tweaked it with some changes such as bidrectional, etc. but don't see visible improvements in the accuracy of the tags. I've read through [the ExtractorFrames JavaDoc page](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/ExtractorFrames.html), but they seem to be using shorthand that I don't quite understand. So:

- What do the different option groups *really* mean?
- Are there combinations that make sense from practice? I'd like to avoid spending a lot of time trying random combinations if certain ones don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Manning explains some of the most commonly used features for POS taggers in more detail in this [Coursera video](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/150).

Regarding sensible feature sets: This heavily depends on the language. You can check out the configurations for the various models that we ship with the tagger on [GitHub](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/scripts/pos-tagger) and if there is one for the language that you build a tagger for, then I'd use that configuration as a starting point for running your experiments.